# Make image height equal to viewport

Tags: html, css

I want to get my image to fill the viewport completely, but it seems it is larger than the viewport.
This is a snippet of my HTML:

```html
<div class="carousel-item active" style="height: 100%;">
  <img src="img/bg13.jpg">
</div>
```

This is my CSS:

```css
html, body {
  height:100%;
}

.carousel-item img {
  height:100%; 
  width: 100%;
}
```

However, the height of the image (893px) is larger than the height of the HTML and body elements (625px).
I thought percentage values were always calculated from a parent value. I imagined it might be calculating the height of the browser screen, but that is only 728px.

I'm aware I can use `vh` to achieve this, but I'm trying to gain an understanding on why this is happening.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: sounds like there is another element in the hierarchy between `body` and your `.carousel-item` div - you'd have to set that/those  to 100% height as well.

Comment: look into object-fit:cover

Comment: I just looked up the object-fit style, and thank you. It is a very useful style! I just found out what caused the large height. I realized the image used its scaled height. So I'll have to explicitly state the height of the elements above it as @johannes said. Thank you.